# Fail of Deployment of Ruby on Rails App in Azure Web App Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I follow some tutorials in order to get a simple application working, but was not successfully. The most simple tutorial is a "hello-world" of this [example](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/ruby/blob/master/tutorials/hello-world/README.md).

The first part is create on my local machine a Ruby application with just a route to a custom message. Running at my machine the application is fine.

After creating a Web App at Azure, Linux based with Ruby 2.3 using local Git Repository, there are some problems regarding to bundle installation.

When I push the application to Git (of Azure), the container install all gems in "tmp/bundle" folder. But, the container fail to start. Checking the error of start up, the container can't find the gem files, especially the puma. When I check the file, there is at same location.

The push of app does not include the gems intalled, because the container can read the Gemfile and install by itself, but for some reason, can't find them.

I don't know where else to find. Anyone could help me with some clues?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I suggest you could make your application into an image before you deploy it on Azure. And then create the Web App for the container.

So you can check everything when you create the image. For step by step, you can follow the document [Use a custom Docker image for Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image).

Comment: That's my plan B. I opened a ticket with Microsoft. I don't understand, things like WebApp should be more easy to deploy than anything else. Probably is a littler configuration that I'm missing. The lack of tutorials and example makes me with no options, sometimes...